# how can I open a modal using javascript after form submission

Tags: javascript, php, modal-dialog

After clicking the submit button , I have some php code that runs and uploads to a database,
is their a way to use javascript to open a modal at the end of the action.php ?

Comment: JavaScript can't open modals in all browsers.

Comment: i was hoping it would be like : echo "<script 
       window.location='home.php';
</script>";

Comment: Well, it [can't in Chrome](http://blog.chromium.org/2014/07/disabling-showmodaldialog.html). But you can ofcourse echo a polyfill (which never will be a real modal).

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you to action async !

Browser :  display modal windows
Server : action.php

And the modal is waiting the end of action.php to disappear. Looks like you need to manually submit your form with an ajax request to action.php and before sending the ajax request enable/show your modal(anyway library or way you want) and when you receive your response form the ajax request you disable the modal .

sounds good?

Comment: yeah , but i dont know ajax, im pretty new to all this

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it without anything fancy just good old if statements.....

i used $_SESSION['show'] as a flag , after the php does its work to upload to the db it sets the flag , when the page reloads after submit button is pressed it gets to an if statement surrounding the code that displays the modal , if flag is set , show the modal...
otherwise do normal behavior and keep it hidden....